# Gradient of a vector-valued function with respect to a matrix domain

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, matrix-calculus

I have a need to calculate the gradient of the following function $f:\mathbb{R}^{k\times m}\to\mathbb{R}^k$ given by
$$f(A)=Ax,$$
for some fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$.  Using coordinates $A=A^i_jE_i^j, x=x^je_j$, we have that
$$f^\lambda(A^i_j)=A^\lambda_jx^j,$$
and trivially
$$\frac{\partial f^\lambda}{\partial A^\mu_\nu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial A^\mu_\nu}(A^\lambda_jx^j)=\delta^\lambda_\mu\delta_j^\nu x^j=\delta^\lambda_\mu x^\nu.$$
However, I'm not sure how to interpret the differential correctly.  If we look at this slightly more abstractly, with the differential $df:T\mathbb{R}^{k\times m}\to T\mathbb{R}^k$, we see that for $v\in T\mathbb{R}^{k\times m}$ and $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k)$ that
\begin{align}
df(v)[g]&=v[g\circ f]\\
&=v^i_j\frac{\partial g}{\partial y^\lambda}\frac{\partial f^\lambda}{\partial A^i_j}
\end{align}
and so
\begin{align}
df(v)&=v^i_j\frac{\partial f^\lambda}{\partial A^i_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\lambda}\\
&=v^i_j\delta^\lambda_ix^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\lambda}\\
&=v^\lambda_jx^j\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\lambda}.
\end{align}

Under more ideal settings, as with the case when $k=1$, we would define $\text{grad}(f)$ to be the unique vector field such that
$$g(\text{grad}(f),v))=df(v)$$
for any $v\in T\mathbb{R}^{k\times m}$ where $g$ is the Frobenius inner product on $k\times m$-matrices (i.e., $g(A,B)=\text{tr}(A^TB)$) and we would conclude from the above calculations that
$$\text{grad}(f)=x.$$
This however doesn't seem to generalize in any obvious way (to me at least).  Am I missing something (or have an error) in the above computation?  If not, what would we conclude is the gradient of $f$?

Comment: The gradient would be a third-order tensor. Have you considered to vectorize $\mathbf{A}$ and compute $\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{A})}$ ? It is relatively easy to do that.

Comment: A third-order tensor on what space?  Vectorizing $A$ should lead to an identical computation (the only difference is a flatening of the indices on $A$), but we would still end up with something of the form $df = c^\lambda_\mu dA^\mu \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial y^\lambda}$, which doesn't make sense since our coordinates are on different manifolds.  Can the pushforward be described as a rank (1,1)-tensor on the product manifold of the domain and range in some capacity?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to consider the $k$th component of $f$ denoted $f_k=\mathbf{e}_k: \mathbf{Ax}$

It follows that
the gradient of this component is the matrix
$$
\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial \mathbf{A}}
= \mathbf{e}_k \mathbf{x}^T
$$
Indeed $f_k$ is only sensitive to elements in the $k$th row of $\mathbf{A}$.